# How to retain foreign key names in DDL generated by Erwin for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, erwin

I'm using ErWin 9.5 to generate DDL for MySQL 5.6 and have hit a snag when creating a foreign key.  MYSQL does not use foreign key name generated by ErWin because the `CONSTRAINT` statement is not included in the DDL.

The DDL ErWin generates for a simple FK relationship is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_two
ADD FOREIGN KEY table_two_ibfk_99b (table_one_id) REFERENCES table_one (table_one_id);
```

When this runs, MySQL generates the constraint with the name `table_two_ibfk_1` and increments from there.

However, if I change the target database in ErWin to anything else it uses the proper syntax with the `CONSTRAINT` statement.  For example, with the target DB set to `ODBC V3`, ErWin generates the following DDL:

```
ALTER TABLE table_two
ADD CONSTRAINT table_two_ibfk_99a FOREIGN KEY (table_one_id) REFERENCES table_one (table_one_id);
```

Problem with just using ODBC is that I loose the ability to `AUTO_INCREMENT` my PKs.

Has anyone found a solution for this?